# Rmarkdown: adding a caption to plot

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, caption

I am using Rmarkdown to create a PDF document. I have a chunk which is supposed to create a plot and add a caption to it. But when I add the `fig.cap` option and also include `echo = FALSE`, the chart gets printed at the end of the document instead of being printed immediately.

When knitting to HTML, the caption kind of works, although formatting is strange, but in PDF the chart gets appended to the end.

````
```{r, warning=FALSE,echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.cap = "test cap"}
## Basic plots
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
plot(y = datas, x = as.Date(dates), type = "l",
     main = "N225", ylab = "value", xlab = "time",
     col = "salmon", frame = FALSE)
lines(y = datas[(length(datas) - 500):length(datas)],
      x = dates[(length(datas) - 500):length(datas)],
      col = "lightblue")
legend(y = 18000, x= as.Date('2015-01-01'),
       legend = c("Train", "Test"),
       col = c("salmon", "lightblue"),
       pch = 19)
plot(y = loret, x = as.Date(dates), type = "h",
     main = "N225 log-returns", ylab = "logreturns", xlab = "time",
     col = "salmon", frame = FALSE)
lines(y = loret[(length(loret) - 500):length(loret)],
      x = dates[(length(loret) - 500):length(loret)],
      col = "lightblue", type = "h")
plot(y = loret^2, x = as.Date(dates), type = "h",
     main = "N225 squared log-returns", ylab = "logreturn", xlab = "time",
     col = "salmon", frame = FALSE)
lines(y = (loret[(length(loret) - 500):length(loret)])^2,
      x = dates[(length(loret) - 500):length(loret)],
      col = "lightblue", type = "h")
```
````

**What I get in HTML**

[image: What I get in HTML]

**What I get in PDF**

[image: What I get in PDF]

Comment: Have you tried `fig.pos: (''H")` as another chunk option?

Comment: @J_F Yes, did not help

Comment: @J_F also, without the `echo=FALSE` it works, but I can't put all my code into the document. There must be some weird problem with `echo=FALSE' and 'fig.caption = "..."` combination

Comment: Can you reproduce the example with example data? It seems to work fine when I try it

Comment: @timfaber there seems to be some sort of page break issue. The chart gets thrown on a new page and the text which is supposed to follow it gets printed on the page before.